# Where can I start to program a S5PV210?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, compiler

At the university I learn only the Microchip microcontroller, but I would like to improve my knowledge. I ordered a development board based on Samsung S5PV210.
The manufacturer also provided a Linux distribution with this development board, but I would like to start from the basic, for example to blink a led, in this case I don't want to install a Linux, I just want to simply blink a led.

Where can I start?

How can I compile such a simple code?

How can I upload the code to the microcontroller?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: From a quick google, it seems that processor is used for Android, at least sometimes. Not sure if that works for you. Android's IDE is Eclipse with the Java language.

Comment: I tried to find a datasheet for the controller, but even the Samsung site doesn't seem to mention it. I'd never buy a SBC if I couldn't get the controller's datasheet. Especially if you want to go real basic. Why did you choose this board in particular? (Also, a name like "S5PV210", what were those marketing guys at Samsung thinking? :-))

Comment: Because it was an acceptable price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S5PV210 probably isn't the best chip to learn on for the reasons stevenvh mentions. I would never buy an SBC before I had already downloaded the manual and given it a quick once over. If you're just learning, a chip/platform with an active community is much more important than price.

That being said, the S5PV210 looks to be an ARM Cortex-A8. So *maybe **maybe***, you *might* be able to get a BeagleBone LED example to work. But this statement comes with absolutely no warranty whatsoever that you will not damage your SBC.

Hopefully the SBC came with schematics and a datasheet for the chip. Read them. Understand them. The following code, read it, understand it. After you feel you understand it all, read it again. You will most likely need to make modifications to make it work.

After you get the code loaded, don't just let it run. Set a breakpoint early on and step through it, making sure everything is behaving as you think it should.

All that being said, have a look at this BeagleBone LED blink example paying special attention to where it states that the Cortex-A8 support is experimental:

http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardOpenOCD#LED_blink_example

Comment: What is the best development board to start with?

Comment: There is no "best". Each one has it's advantage and disadvantages. It depends on what you are looking to do. If you are just looking to learn another microcontroller, Arduino has one of the larger, more active communities and so help and examples are always readily available. I also am a fan of the MSP430, especially if you want to do low power projects. If you are looking for something more substantial, the BeagleBone as mentioned above also has a pretty active community and has an ARM Cortex-A8 similar to what you have already.

Answer (score 1):

For s5PV210 samsung board, looks like you are towards cortex A series architecture. It is design for mobile application, especially Android.

Usually if you buy development board, it will includes BSP support, which are OS images, source and sample codes and compiler tools.

You can start download eclipse and build the tools like Sourcery G++ Lite with a eclipse plugins.

Also with eclipse you can develop android platform with ARM DS-5 community edition and go crazy with Android NDK application which support debugging to the s5pv210 board.

All of them are available for free download.